# Analog Multimeter Won't Zero Ohm Scale

Tags: multimeter

Multimeter ohm scale won't zer0. Analog GB Instruments GMT-312 on OHM setting with leads touching and needle stays offscale way right to <0. Tried Ohm zero-adjust dial, new battery. Also, V reads 25% hi on both AC & DC (Ex: 150V instead of 120V at all outlets).  Rarely used, ~5 years old. Time for new meter?

Comment: Are the leads in the correct port(s)? Many meters use a different port for one or both leads when measuring Amps .vs. when measuring Volts and Ohms. Results may be unexpected if using the wrong port. Also - is the Volts 0 at 0? Analog meers often have an adjustment for the needle (affecting all scales) as well as the Ohms Zero Adjust.

Comment: You've only got two ports on that meter so if you're reading 150 volts on 120V outlets.... I'd get a new meter. You might want to upgrade... a 15 dollar meter is not going to be very reliable.

Comment: Although getting a high-quality meter these days may be a bit difficult. My order for a standard Fluke meter from a large well-known distributor is still on back order more than 3 months later...

Comment: Ecnerwal:  Leads inserted iaw manual, red in +(V,Ohm,A), black in -(COM).  Volts zero at left end of scales.

Comment: If your batteries are new then, step 2 analog meters have a mechanical adjustment screw on the face plate bottom center of the meter movement. “Frapping” the movement or using the wrong scale or function can cause the needle to bend slightly so mechanical adjustment is needed this is a rough adjustment but will normally recover a slightly bent needle in some cases the protective plastic needs to be removed, sometimes it’s a plastic plug over the plastic adjustment. Care and a fine screw driver may be the fix you need.

Answer (score 3):

Given the further information in comments, we have

Volt - scale - zero is at zero, reads high on both AC & DC

Ohms - won't zero.

Replace it. Yes, it's time for a new meter.

Unless you have a particular love of analog meters, a moderately priced Digital meter is probably your best bet for occasional use. Beware of non-listed cheap junk from large websites (with names evocative of rivers, alleys, and others) where you end up (perhaps unwittingly) buying direct import and may get stuff that's not UL listed. That's the kind of cheap that can be expensive.

But you don't need the most expensive thing out there, either. Plenty of moderately priced legitimately imported UL-listed (or other Nationally Recognized Laboratory listed, in other countries) meters available - not sure there's much of any not imported at this point.

Lifetime-wise, I have multiple digital meters at multiple price points, and not one is as young as 5 years. Some cheapies to have in the cars, at least one that lasted much longer than Radio Shack who sold it, an AC/DC clamp-meter that was a conscious choice not to spend ~6 times as much on a Fluke 25 years ago, still working fine.

Pretty sure my Kill-a-Watt is more than 5 now as well, and that's the bees knees when you want to check an outlet (assembled) or see how much current a plugged in device draws without having to fuss with dubious wiring to make measurement possible.